# If using all scalar values, you must pass an index error when changing API into string

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to hide my API key as I want to share my code in a repo. Unfortunately, my attempt at representing my API as a string automatically mucks up my ability to turn my get request into a data frame. I find this weird as when I would initially just have my API code in the get request instead of 'API' as the representation of my API it would work totally fine. What is the issue here?

````
API = os.getenv('API_KEY')

IQ = requests.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock-screener?marketCapMoreThan=1&dividendMoreThan=0&limit=100000000&&apikey=API').json()

Stocks = pd.DataFrame(IQ) Stocks.set_index("symbol", inplace = True)```

response:
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
````

Answer (score 1):

As you have written it, the apikey is equal to the string 'API'. Use this instead:

```
IQ = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock-screener?marketCapMoreThan=1&dividendMoreThan=0&limit=100000000&&apikey={API}').json()
```

Comment: I gave this a go although I am still getting the same error response.

Comment: What is the difference between the value of IQ when using `API` and when using the apikey? Add a print statement right after the request and compare both results. Maybe the response is different (it shouldn't though).